# Django modelling - using the right relationships

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want a model 'Model' to have a set (zero or more) of 'Attribute's. It should be able to access these 'Attribute's. A single 'Attribute' has exactly ONE 'Model'.

A 'Model' has zero or more 'Objects'. It should be able to access these 'Object's. A single 'Object' has exactly ONE 'Model'. An 'Object' will inherit all the 'Attribute's of it's 'Model'.

I'm not sure how to create these models in Django.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    #

class Attribute(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model)

class Object(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model)
```

**UPDATE**

When I try to make an 'Object' object, I get this error:

```
column myproject_object.model_id does not exist
```

Similarly, if I try to make a 'Model' object. I get this error:

```
null value in column "attributes_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: What you have seems perfectly right. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Neither of those have anything to do with your model structure. The first problem appears to be that you have not migrated your database since adding the ForeignKey field. And the second must be to do with how you are creating a model object, but you haven't shown that code so it's impossible to know exactly what.

Answer (score 0):

This relation is called Many-to-many relationship and Django has implemented it in its ORM.

```
 class Child(models.Model):
     # [...]

 class Parent(models.Model):
     children = models.ManyToManyField(Model)
```

You can access in this way

```
 parent = Parent()
 parent.save()
 parent.children.all()
```

Django create automatically the relation in database, I highly recommend you to read the [Django documentation about Many-to-many relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: I don't see how this models what I want. ManyToMany relation is used for when A has many of B and B has many of A. For me, a 'Model' has many 'Objects', but an 'Object' has only ONE 'Model'. And this also doesn't seem to fix the 'Attribute's problem.

Comment: I have no solution except a homemade relation based on foreign key and `unique` or `unique_together`. But you can see [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2552/) if it helps you.